# Pass your password to your SSH key via a script

Tags: ssh, bash, scripting, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I am writing a script that will allow me to retrieve a file from all of my servers at once. I have SSH keys in place in order to log into my servers. My SSH key however requires a password.

The script I am writing will not be automated, it will only ever be run manually. So my script prompts the user for the SSH key password.

How can I send the password to the SSH key as it connects to each server. I am trying to avoid having to type my password in for each server.

I know I could use 'expect', but am hoping there is a simple way to do this. Maybe some environment variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why not use `ssh-agent` for this?
See the man page for additional details. :)

Comment: To be honest, I've never felt that ssh-agent was a secure idea. I don't really like the idea of it storing my keys. I am probably being overly paranoid though.

Comment: The alternative you're proposing is providing a method of getting the encrypted key and password to decrypt it from the filesystem. I can't readily imagine a circumstance in which this is less secure than the unencrypted key being held within a program's memory.

Comment: Please describe your security concerns with ssh-agent. (ssh-agent doesn't "store" your key)

Comment: the agent is at least as secure as putting your password in a file (more secure if the file isn't mode 600 or more restricted), and far more secure than letting it sit in a shell/environment variable :-)  -- If you're paranoid you can always kill off the agent when your script is done.

Comment: I agree with voretaq7. Your passphrase will have to be stored in plaintext *somewhere*. At that point it's not more secure than having an unencrypted private key in the first place.

Comment: I definitely wasn't thinking of storing the password. My concern is if I walk away from my desk for a second, someone can get access to the servers because of the agent. If I use a script, once my script stops, no one can get access to the servers without my password.

Comment: @mhost The simple and obvious solution: Lock your screen before you walk away, and don't share your login info.  The less simple solution: Spawn the agent, load the key, spawn & background all your SSH subprocess, kill the agent (waiting for the subprocesses to terminate is left as an exercise for the scripter :-)

Comment: I do always lock my screen. It's more just a precaution in case I ever forget. Anyways, this does answer my question. I really just wanted to know if there was a built-in way to do this. I will use ssh-agent. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a SSH key that doesn't have a passkey.  It may be less secure, but any method that will allow unattended use will have the same flaw.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my 2 cents!

- I have a USB drive that is always with me (in my physical key chain).
- I make a second partition of 5 insignificant MB in it. This partition is an encrypted ext4 partition.
- I store my private key (without passkey) in that encrypted partition.
- In my computer I store the password to decrypt this partition in the file manager (I use dolphin) so if I plug the USB drive I can mount the encrypted partition with two single clicks, and if I plug the USB drive in another computer I can mount it typing the password.
- Again in my computer I have symlinked my private keys from it usually are (~/.ssh/id_rsa) to where they are when mounted with the USB drive. So once mounted I can make a usual ssh without password.
- If I am in another computer I can tell ssh where my key is with the -i flag

This way I can:

- Login comfortably from my everyday computer
- Log in with a single password from any linux machine
- Have my private keys always safe with me and in a encrypted filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Expect is the solution that comes to mind first...

[Check this script example](http://rootprompt.org/article.php3?article=9187), as it is close to what you're looking for.

Comment: Expect, and any other form of scripting, is a really poor solution to this problem.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that too, but I was just wondering if there was a simple way. Like you can do with gpg passwords.

Comment: Obviously there are security issues in this case, but expect is a useful tool for people to know about.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is installing package `sshpass` and use it like:
 `sshpass -p password ssh -i keyfile.pem user@server`